# Trouble calculating the line Integral of a vector field

Tags: integration, vector-fields

Let $\gamma$ be the curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by
$$
\gamma(t)=\begin{pmatrix}
1-\frac{\cos(t)}{2}\\ 
\sin(t)\\ 
\sin(t)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
for $t\in [0,1]$, and define the vector field $F$ by
$$
F(x,y,z)=\begin{pmatrix}
2x(y+z)\\ 
x^2+y^2\\ 
x^2+2yz
\end{pmatrix}
$$
for $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3$. First, we see that
$$
F(\gamma(t))=\begin{pmatrix}
2\left ( 1-\frac{1}{2}\cos(t) \right )2\sin( t)\\ 
\left ( 1-\frac{1}{2}\cos( t) \right )^2+\sin^2(t)\\ 
\left ( 1-\frac{1}{2}\cos( t) \right )^2+2\sin^2( t)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
then it takes really long time to calculate $F(\gamma(t))\cdot\gamma'(t)$, and then determining $\int_{0}^{1}F(\gamma(t))\cdot\gamma'(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$. I am asking if there is a shorter way to do that, or some lemma to get past the tedious part. Using the calculator, the integral will be zero.

Comment: Given that curve with that parametrization? No, there doesn't seem to be a really shorter way to do that. Perhaps a litte algebraic trick here and there, but basically that's what you've got to do.

Comment: Is the $t$ range $[0, 1]$ or $[0, 2 \pi]$?